# Executorservice shutdown and restart with Spring

Tags: java, spring, shutdown, executorservice

I am using an `ExecutorService` in my application and with a fixed thread pool. I have declared it in my spring xml file as

```
<bean id="executorService" 
      class="java.util.concurrent.Executors" 
      factory-method="newFixedThreadPool" 
      destroy-method="shutdownNow">
    <constructor-arg value="5"/>
</bean>
```

Now there is a situation in my code where I have to force shutdown (using `shutdownNow`) the `ExecutorService` and then restart it. I am really new with Spring and am unaware of how to do it. As of now I just submit tasks to the service and then do a `shutdownNow`, but my requirement says I want to restart the service.

Comment: You might be able to get away with calling afterPropertiesSet() assuming you actually implemented the setup code there for bean initialization.

Comment: No, I am not using afterPropertiesSet(). It is an inherited spring code. The initialization is done in the main() method and stays from there. I want to know a way in which I can reinitialize a "property" for a bean or else in case of a shutdownNow for my service, I will have to reinitialize the entire bean?

Answer (score 1):

May I recommend simply managing the `ExecutorService` yourself behind a bean. This way you can provide api for your bean to shutdown and recreate a brand new Executor service.

```
public class ExecutorServiceHolder {

    private ExecutorService executorService;

    //set this through normal Spring config
    private int numThreads;

    @PostConstruct //once the properties have been, initialize your executorservice..
    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        this.executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numThreads);
    }

    //This is just pseudo-code, you may want to enhance with more thorough checking 
    //to make sure that the previous pool is shutdown..
    public synchronized void shutDownAndRestart() {
        this.executorService.shutdownNow();
        this.executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numThreads);
    }
```

Comment: This looks something nice. I can try this! Thanks :)

Comment: Such kind of holder does not seems to be a good idea for me.  Beans that originally using an `ExecutorService` to submit tasks, will now need to be injected with that `ExecutorServiceHolder` and get the executorService from it.  I think it is a better idea to make a decorator/wrapper of `ExecutorService` instead which will deal with the "restart", so bean using `ExecutorService` (except the one responsible to restart it) will be transparent to such change